# I'm unable to receive the json object sent from my servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var path = null;
        console.log('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/loadfile');
        $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/loadfile',
              success: function(data){
                $.each(data,function(index,obj){
                    console.log(obj.id);
                    alert('inside');
                    path = obj.path;
                });  
              }     
              });
```

here /loadfile is the url which returns the json object , when I go to this url I am able to see the JSON object printed on the html page , however I dont get the same when I access the page which contains the above javascript code

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: Is they any request in the network tab of the dev tools, what is its response?

Comment: Is your server telling the browser it's json or are you assuming the browser just magically knows? Setting datatype is jQuery is not enough. Not just what does `console.log(data)` show and network tab doesn't show enough about the data, if `console.log(data)` shows the data, does it show a clickable expandable object or a string? If it's the latter, what I just said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often people don't tell their server to the the browser that the JSON string they are sending is to be interpreted as a json object.

Despite the fact that `dataType:'json'` is supposed to sort it out, it is not always the case.

in PHP

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

ASP

```
Response.AddHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Failing that,

```
success: function(data){
    if (typeof data!='object') data=$.parseJSON(data); // make sure it's an object
```

I can't figure out why jQuery doesn't fix it but the response headers, even with dataType:'json' set can appear as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` and the object doesn't get created.